# How to use pretty URLs (BrowserRouter) with react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-router, admin-on-rest, react-admin

Is there a way to use BrowserRouter with react-admin to have URLs without the `#` character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to supply your own history. See https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#history

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createHistory();

const App = () => (
    <Admin history={history}>
        ...
    </Admin>
);
```